# Programming advice for PHP json_encode array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to output a JSON response using PHP5 that looks similar to the following:

```
{"success": true, "years": [{"yearnumber": 2012},{"yearnumber": 2013},...]}
```

I have gotten as far as:

```
$rt = array();
$rt["success"] = true;
$rt["years"] = array();
for ($i=date('Y') ; $i < (date('Y')+21) ; $i++) {
     $rt['years'][]= 'yearnumber:'.$i;
}
echo json_encode($rt);
```

Ofcourse this is not the proper way to achieve my goal - and it obviously doesn't produce the desired results.

I am fairly new to PHP programming and could use a little push here.  Thanks.

Comment: You want to output invalid JSON? You are gonna have to build the string yourself.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: Did you want the years array to look like this: "years": [{"yearnumber": 2012}, {"yearnumber": 2013}]?

Comment: How is the JSON invalid?

Comment: The output is "yearnumber:2012" and I need "yearnumber":2012

Comment: @JackWink - I apologize for the original post - yes - it needs to look like your example

Answer (score 3):

To get this (The closest valid JSON that would be what I think you want):

```
{"success":true, "years":[2012,2013,...]}
```

You can use:

```
$rt = array();
$rt["success"] = true;
$rt["years"] = array();
for ($i=intval(date('Y')) ; $i < (date('Y')+21) ; $i++) {
     $rt['years'][]= $i;
}
echo json_encode($rt);
//{"success":true,"years":[2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022,2023,2024,2025,2026,2027,2028,2029,2030,2031,2032]}
```

For `"years": [{"yearnumber": 2012}, {"yearnumber": 2013}]`

You can use:

```
$rt = array();
$rt["success"] = true;
$rt["years"] = array();
for ($i=intval(date('Y')) ; $i < (date('Y')+21) ; $i++) {
     $rt['years'][]= array("yearnumber" => $i);
}
echo json_encode($rt);
//{"success":true,"years":[{"yearnumber":2012},{"yearnumber":2013},{"yearnumber":2014},{"yearnumber":2015},{"yearnumber":2016},{"yearnumber":2017},{"yearnumber":2018},{"yearnumber":2019},{"yearnumber":2020},{"yearnumber":2021},{"yearnumber":2022},{"yearnumber":2023},{"yearnumber":2024},{"yearnumber":2025},{"yearnumber":2026},{"yearnumber":2027},{"yearnumber":2028},{"yearnumber":2029},{"yearnumber":2030},{"yearnumber":2031},{"yearnumber":2032}]}
```

Though it appears redundant to me

Comment: Thanks Esailija:  Now I see what you meant by invalid JSON...my original post with incorrect.  I will try your suggestion...redundant - yes but it's how the data stores work in the framework I am using.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
{"success":true, "years":["yearnumber":2012,"yearnumber":2013,...]}
```

is not valid JSON. Arrays (`[]`) can't have keys in them, only values. The best solution (in this scenario) is to just cut they keys since they're all the same anyway (See Esailija's answer)

Another way would be to create an array of objects like this

```
{"success":true, "years":[{"yearnumber":2012},{"yearnumber":2013},...]}
```

To achieve that from PHP:

```
$rt = array();
$rt["success"] = true;
$rt["years"] = array();
for ($i=intval(date('Y')) ; $i < (date('Y')+21) ; $i++) {
     $rt['years'][] = array('yearnumber' => $i);
}
echo json_encode($rt);
```